# Sort sub elements of array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this one:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Mickey
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Donald
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Goofy
        )
    )
```

Is there a way to sort in alphabetical order the 'name' field?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Using a callback method for [usort()](http://php.net/usort);

```
function my_sorter($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
}

usort($list, 'my_sorter');
```

Comment: If you're using PHP 5.3 or later, you can pass a closure instead of a string for the callback:

`usort($list, function($a, $b) { return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']); });`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `usort()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 0):

usort works fine. The function passed to usort should be a comparison function, which returns a value less than one if ab, and 0 if a==b. Because of how your arrays are formatted, your comparison function should compare a['name'] and b['name']. So:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a['name'],$b['name']);
}
$a = array(array("id" => 2, "name" => "Donald"),array("id" => 3, "name" => "Goofy"),array("id" => 4, "name" => "Mickey"));
usort($a, "cmp");
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: ".$value['name']."\n";
}
```